# Error running old react native code on m1 mac

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

switching to an m1 mac from an intel my react native code has this error

Error: cannot find the node binary. Try setting the NODE_BINARY variable in the  "Bundle React Native code and images" Build Phase to the absolute path to your node binary.  You can find it by executing "which node" in a terminal window.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Although I've set it with this

[image]

I'm not sure how else to set it

react-native-0.65.1
xcode - 15.2
mac - m1